# How to increase the size of a boson in tikz-feynman package?

Tags: tikz-feynman, feynmf

I am using the `tikz-feynman` package to make some Feynman diagrams like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Beta decay
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{feynmf}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a);
    \vertex [above right = 5 cm of a] (u11);
    \vertex [above left = 5 cm of u11] (u12);
    \vertex [right = 0.4 cm of a] (b);
    \vertex [above right = 5 cm of b] (u21);
    \vertex [above left = 5 cm of u21] (u22);
    \vertex [right = 0.4 cm of b] (c);
    \vertex [above right = 5 cm of c] (u31);
    \vertex [above left = 5 cm of u31] (u32);
    \vertex [above right = 2 cm of u31] (f1);
    \vertex [above right = 3 cm of f1] (f2);
    \vertex [below right = 3 cm of f1] (f3);
    
    \diagram* {
      (a) -- [fermion] (u11) -- [fermion] (u12),
      (b) -- [fermion] (u21) -- [fermion] (u22),
      (c) -- [fermion] (u31) -- [fermion] (u32),
      (u31) -- [boson] (f1),
      (f1) -- [fermion] (f2);
      (f1) -- [fermion] (f3);
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But I am having two issues:

1. I cannot get the zigzag line for the boson, it looks identical to a photon. The zigzag line is supported in `feynmf` package but I am not sure if I can incorporate that in a diagram that uses TikZ.
2. I want to be able to make the boson appear out more, so the amplitude of the wave should be larger, but I don't see a way to do that either. I tried the options of changing `size=#` or using the key `large`, but neither of them work.

Comment: You can illustrate your desire which you need to achieve.

Comment: So instead of it looking like the first diagram here: http://ivtools.sourceforge.net/ivtools/latexbuttons/feynman/index.html, I want it to look like diagram (a) here: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Feynman-diagrams-contributing-to-the-elementary-N-elastic-scattering-amplitude-a_fig1_258020046

Comment: You can _draw your desire by hand_ and post in your question such as anyone can help you from **it**.

Comment: Thanks for your reputations, my answer is now improved too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the style of a `tikz-feynman` element (such as `boson`) using the `\tikzfeynmanset` command. However, normally this command appends to the predefining style instead of overwriting it, which in this case means you still get the sine wave for the boson *mixed* with some other pattern.

To actually redefine the element you can set the internal element `boson@@` with `\tikzfeynmanset`. Because this name contains an `@` symbol you need to put `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` around the code for the modification. Other than that you can just copy the relevant piece of the source code from `tikz-feynman` and modify any part of the style.

The zigzag pattern is predefined in the TikZ `decorations.pathmorphing` library, with the option `amplitude` to influence the size of the pattern. This library is already loaded by `tikz-feynman` (for other decorations such as the sine wave for photons), so you don't need to load the library separately.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\makeatletter
\tikzfeynmanset{/tikzfeynman/every boson@@/.style={
    /tikz/draw=none,
    /tikz/decoration={name=none},
    /tikz/postaction={
      /tikz/draw,
      /tikz/decoration={
        zigzag,
        amplitude=2mm,
      },
      /tikz/decorate=true,
    }
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a);
    \vertex [above right = 5 cm of a] (u11);
    \vertex [above left = 5 cm of u11] (u12);
    \vertex [right = 0.4 cm of a] (b);
    \vertex [above right = 5 cm of b] (u21);
    \vertex [above left = 5 cm of u21] (u22);
    \vertex [right = 0.4 cm of b] (c);
    \vertex [above right = 5 cm of c] (u31);
    \vertex [above left = 5 cm of u31] (u32);
    \vertex [above right = 2 cm of u31] (f1);
    \vertex [above right = 3 cm of f1] (f2);
    \vertex [below right = 3 cm of f1] (f3);
    
    \diagram* {
      (a) -- [fermion] (u11) -- [fermion] (u12),
      (b) -- [fermion] (u21) -- [fermion] (u22),
      (c) -- [fermion] (u31) -- [fermion] (u32),
      (u31) -- [boson] (f1),
      (f1) -- [fermion] (f2);
      (f1) -- [fermion] (f3);
      (f2) -- [photon] (f3);
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

For comparison I also added a photon between two random nodes (that probably violates some laws of physics).

Note: to make your code more clear it would be a good idea not to mix `tikz-feynman` and `feynmf`, unless strictly necessary.

Comment: What is the purpose of writing this `/tikz/decoration={name=none}`?

Comment: @AndréC I am not really sure, I tried to keep as close as possible to the `tikz-feynman` source, which specifies this key for `boson` as well as for most other diagram elements.

Comment: When you put this line as a comment, the result is the same, I wonder why the maintainer wrote it.

Comment: @AndréC actually for this package the `.sty` file is on CTAN, http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-feynman/tikz-feynman.sty (see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman and click on the Sources link). However, usually I just open the `.sty` file from the LaTeX installation directory on my own pc. The folder can be found by typing `kpsewhich tikz-feynman.sty` in a terminal, or by running a `.tex` file that uses the package and checking the log file.

Comment: Indeed, I had downloaded the wrong package. I avoid looking at the sources in MikTeX because I like to tinker with them.

Comment: In my opinion, you should put `decoration=snake`.

Comment: @AndréC of course when you find the source on your PC then you can copy/save it at another location to try things out, without modifiying the original files.

Comment: The OP asked for zigzag (also the link that he gave in the comments was a 'real' zigzag with straight edges) but of course `snake` could also be an option.

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right.

Comment: +1, I hadn't thought about changing the style in the code.

Comment: Thanks so much! The other question I had was about changing the size of the photon and I'm guessing I'll have to make a custom element with a different size. In order to get a squiggly line, what will I have to change the zigzag to in your code to get a photon instead? Also, I'll select your answer as the best one since you answered first and your answer is almost the same as the other one

Comment: @AlwaysLearningForever the normal `photon` decoration is called `complete sines` and it also has an `amplitude` option to set the size (default `1mm`).

Comment: @Marijn I am so sorry, I accidentally chose a different answer to give bounty to

Comment: @AlwaysLearningForever no problem, the other answer is very nice I think :)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, as described in the manual, to create your own style. Here I have created the `yourboson` style colored blue (but of course modifiable).

```
\tikzfeynmanset{
yourboson/.style={
blue,
decoration={zigzag,amplitude=2mm,segment length=4mm,pre,pre length=2pt, post,post length=2pt},decorate}
}
```

The advantage is that it keeps the original style intact.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations}

\tikzfeynmanset{
yourboson/.style={
blue,
decoration={zigzag,amplitude=2mm,segment length=4mm,pre,pre length=2pt, post,post length=2pt},decorate}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a);
    \vertex [above right = 5 cm of a] (u11);
    \vertex [above left = 5 cm of u11] (u12);
    \vertex [right = 0.4 cm of a] (b);
    \vertex [above right = 5 cm of b] (u21);
    \vertex [above left = 5 cm of u21] (u22);
    \vertex [right = 0.4 cm of b] (c);
    \vertex [above right = 5 cm of c] (u31);
    \vertex [above left = 5 cm of u31] (u32);
    \vertex [above right = 2 cm of u31] (f1);
    \vertex [above right = 3 cm of f1] (f2);
    \vertex [below right = 3 cm of f1] (f3);
    
    \diagram* {
      (a) -- [fermion] (u11) -- [fermion] (u12),
      (b) -- [fermion] (u21) -- [fermion] (u22),
      (c) -- [fermion] (u31) -- [fermion] (u32),
      (u31) -- [yourboson] (f1),
      (f1) -- [fermion] (f2);
      (f1) -- [fermion] (f3);
    };
  \end{feynman}
  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case `[decoration=zigzag]` after `\begin{tikzpicture}` is not necessary I think?

Comment: You're right, it's a remnant of my failed attempts! Thank you !